# Continue a script after an exception is thrown PHP

Tags: php, exception, try-catch, pdfparser

I'm using the [PDFParser](https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser) and encountering a thrown exception that breaks my script even if I put it in a `try/catch` block like below. Meaning, the exception gets `echo`ed but the `"Caught exception: "` part does not. I thought this was exactly what `try/catch` was for?

```
    try {
        $text = $pdf->getText();
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
```

The [github issue comments](https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser/search?q=Missing%20catalog&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) don't address this issue so I thought SO could help.

Comment: Are you in a namespaced file? Have you aliased `Exception`? What's the message?

Comment: Yes it is namespaced, `namespace Smalot\PdfParser;`. [Here's the file](https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser/blob/159ad7229f67efa184b75a0b4c2076a10d13f6d7/src/Smalot/PdfParser/Document.php). The exception is `Missing catalog`.

Comment: Then it should be `catch (\Exception $e)` surely? Btw, I was talking about _your_ script, not their code.

Comment: ah so stupid of me, that works, thanks!

Comment: No worries, easy miss :)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem of missing catalog fatal error.

I have tried try, throw and catch and now i am not getting any missing catalog fatal error.
Below is the code where i have applied try, throw and catch:

```
public function getPages()
      {
 try{   
      if (isset($this->dictionary['Catalog'])) {
      // Search for catalog to list pages.
      $id = reset($this->dictionary['Catalog']);

    /** @var Pages $object */
    $object = $this->objects[$id]->get('Pages');
    if (method_exists($object, 'getPages')) {
        $pages = $object->getPages(true);
        return $pages;
    }
}

if (isset($this->dictionary['Pages'])) {
    // Search for pages to list kids.
    $pages = array();

    /** @var Pages[] $objects */
    $objects = $this->getObjectsByType('Pages');
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        $pages = array_merge($pages, $object->getPages(true));
    }

    return $pages;
}

if (isset($this->dictionary['Page'])) {
    // Search for 'page' (unordered pages).
    $pages = $this->getObjectsByType('Page');

    return array_values($pages);
}

throw new \Exception('Missing catalog.');
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
$pages = '0';
}
}
```

Best of luck!!